# Creat a bootable ISO file from the command prompt?

Tags: boot, powershell, batch, iso-image, winpe

I have a bootable flash drive with a WINPE install on it, and I would like to be able to **convert said bootable usb to an iso file** **from a batch or powershell file**. I've tried using tools like Folder2iso, but it does not support creating an iso file that is bootable. ImgBurn seemed promising but not matter how much I mess with the config, the iso never boots, plus it is not easy to make portable which is something I need for the program I am creating.

**After doing some more digging, I can create an iso like this:**

```
pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg                   
xcopy "F:\" "%temp%\WinPECopy\media\"
xcopy "C:\WinPE_amd64\fwfiles" "%temp%\WinPECopy\fwfiles\"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\MakeWinPEMedia.cmd" /ISO "%temp%\WinPECopy" "C:\WinPE_Copy.iso"
```

But then I get the following error:
[image: boot]
This is probably because I added the NET framework and custom files to the USB drive, but used the default unaltered efisys.bin file from C:\WinPE_amd64\fwfiles.
You can see this in the `CreateWinPEMedia.cmd` file here:

```
:ISOWorker_OscdImgCommand

  rem
  rem Set the correct boot argument based on availability of boot apps
  rem
  set BOOTDATA=1#pEF,e,b"%WORKINGDIR%\%FWFILES%\efisys.bin"
  if exist "%WORKINGDIR%\%FWFILES%\etfsboot.com" (
    set BOOTDATA=2#p0,e,b"%WORKINGDIR%\%FWFILES%\etfsboot.com"#pEF,e,b"%WORKINGDIR%\%FWFILES%\efisys.bin"
  )

  rem
  rem Create the ISO file using the appropriate OSCDImg command
  rem
  echo Creating %DEST%...
  echo.
  oscdimg -bootdata:%BOOTDATA% -u1 -udfver102 "%WORKINGDIR%\%TEMPL%" "%DEST%" >NUL
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to create "%DEST%" file.
    goto fail
  )
```

Anyone know how I can get around this? I tried deleting the `etfsboot.com` file since it seems to handle whether or not the file is there, but then I get the `Failed to boot: No bootable medium found.` error.

**Another update**

I think I'm on to something, as I figure this out I'm seeing that this is sort of an XY question (pointed out by @Biswapriy). I think I can make it not an XY question but I have to do a bit more research first.

So far I'm thinking:

```
setps:
1. Mount the USB Drive
2. Copy everything to a folder (backup2 script)
3. unmount the usb drive
4. Create new WinPE base: copype amd64 C:\WinPE_ISO_START
5. mount the new image: dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\WinPE_ISO_START\media\boot.wim" /index:1 /MountDir:"C:\WinPE_ISO_START\mount"
6. restore from the copy
7. Unmount the image: dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\WinPE_ISO_START\mount: /commit
8. Create the iso: makewinpemedia /iso "C:\WinPE_ISO_START" "C:\Changed iso.iso"
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive

Comment: That talks about creating an ISO, not converting an altered usb drive to an iso.

Comment: This look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not do it as documented by Microsoft? As you are modifying critical files the error is obvious. You can modify WinPE by mounting the boot.wim file with dism.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of figuring that out. I'm working on a program that allows you to manage winpe drives, and one common feature that has been requested is the ability to save a winpe usb drive to an iso so it can be tested on virtualbox or made into a CD. I don't fully understand WINPE yet so I'm trying to ask as best as I can. If you don't mind bearing with me I think I'll be able to make it less of an XY problem once I figure a bit more out. See the steps update above

Comment: I have another question related to this. Will come back and edit/answer this question once I've figured this out. https://superuser.com/questions/1537578/dism-unable-to-unmount-directory-changed @Biswapriyo

Comment: The Windows ADK and WinPE files are required for creating a bootable WinPE ISO with a UFD filesystem - specifically `oscdimg` is required on the backend, whereas the `MakeWinPeMedia` script is used to make the command simpler _(e.g. `MakeWinPeMedia /iso "C:\WinPE" "C:\WinPE\WinPE.iso"` versus the complex `oscdimg` command)_. .NET framework should have nothing to do with booting, as it would be added to the `boot.wim`, correct? Windows boots in a very straightforward manner, so while I can't determine what this issue is, I do know [this](https://superuser.com/a/1632315/529800) method works

Answer (score 0):

1. Obtain ISO from VLC with *install.wim* file instead of *install.edf*
2. Mount ISO and copy files into a folder
   (mine is: *C:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10*)
3. Mount extracted ISO files to a folder designated for mounting:

```
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10\sources\install.wim /Index:5 /MountDir:C:\TempPath\Mount
```

4. Open the mounted image in Mount folder and navigate to *C:\Windows* and create a *Panther/Unattend* folder, then add the *unattend.xml* file.
5. Unmount the image: `Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\TempPath\Mount /Commit`
6. Create ISO from the folder *C:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10*:
   Open Deployment Imaging tool as Admin
   Run Command:

```
oscdimg.exe -m -o -u2 -udfver102 -bootdata:2#p0,e,bC:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10\boot\etfsboot.com#pEF,e,bC:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10\efi\microsoft\boot\efisys.bin C:\TempPath\WindowsImages\ExtractedOriginalISO\Windows10 C:\TempPath\WindowsImages\WindowsLVT.iso
```